# Different behavior with display:table/table-cell across browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I using Twitter's Bootstrap and this color picker: http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/colorpicker/.

And I'm having an issue with these div/span/input created by library.
It uses bootstrap classes the apply `display: table` to div, `display: table-cell` to span and `display: inline-block` to input.

I've overwritten some CSS attributes to get my expected layout, testing it in Chrome.

However, it does not work as expected in IE9 and Firefox. Works as expected in Chrome, Opera, IE10 (and IE9@IE10).

I've reproduced it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2z7K/2/), here is the important code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="btn">
        <span></span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   line-height: 20px;
}
div {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
}
span.btn {
    background: #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    position: relative;
        left: 90px;
}
span.btn > span {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -42px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Why this is exactly happening? Every browser interpreting `display: table/table-cell` differently?**

**What is the cross-browser solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Firefox doesn't support `position: relative;` on table cells...

[Bug Report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168)

---

The issue is that you are actually having some really weird markup and CSS positioning, you should consider nesting an `absolute` positioned element under a `relative` positioned parent.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2z7K/3/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2z7K/4/) *(With a center black box)*

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 30px;
}

div input {
    padding: 6px;
}

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #aaa;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.. just changing relative by absolute make things right in all browsers

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo Yes it will, that's what positioning is for :)