# CSS horizontal line in the middle of a td

Tags: html, css, html-table

The idea is, in a table, inside a td put a line in the middle of such, like this:

[image: 1]

That you can write in it and the line stays there, like a "line background", but inside the td

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yea pretty fancy, did you tried?

Comment: Not the best solution but what about canvas or background image

Comment: @NicoO Give me the code, that's the question

Comment: @Mr.Alien That is a pretty good question indeed

Comment: @NicoO Basically, i want to do a music sheet in a table, with the C,D,E... and, if you know about music, the notes are placed down, up and in the line, so when is up and down i use the css border-top, border-bottom, in the middle is the problem

Comment: By now i try to do a line by text-decoration, but it doesn't work when is no words in it, draw a line by css and try to move a border to the middle, that's all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strikeout an entire table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204677/strikeout-an-entire-table-row)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619542/linethrough-strikethrough-a-whole-html-table-row

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways

1)  Add HTML `<strike>` or `<del>`.

2) use css property, `text-decoration: line-through;`

3) Using CSS:

```
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

td:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/J6zn5/)

**EDIT**: Since there is a bug in firefox related to position: relative and td element, wrap the text in a div of each td and use the same above css.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/J6zn5/3/)**

**EDIT 2**: In the comments below, @NicoO showed that the firefox bug can be resolved by giving `line-height: 0` to the `tr` element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/J6zn5/6/)**

Comment: `position: relative;` will fail on Firefox for `td` - [Take a read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21554792/1542290)

Comment: @Mr.Alien hey yes.. it is not working.. anyway you might knew?

Comment: Just found `.iWouldLikeToAbsolutelyPositionThingsInsideOfFrickingTableCellsPlease()` jQuery plugin at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/) :)

Comment: @HashemQolami LOL, method name is so ugly

Comment: And as expected, he is appending the `div`, even OP can do that if he can modify his HTML

Comment: I think only the last one is perfect, the first two solutions might not be exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @KingKing yup I think the same (realized after posting it) but kept for other future readers..

Comment: @Mr_Green, maybe you want to post this version to your answer as well? http://jsfiddle.net/J6zn5/5/

Comment: @NicoO that looks nice to me.. why don't you post it ?

Comment: It's basically your answer. This is just some Firefox bug workaround thing I added.

Comment: @NicoO I updated my post.. please check if I miss anything.

Comment: nope. Looks pretty good- thank you. Your edit is better anyway ;) no problem.

Comment: @NicoO oops sorry.. your edit gone.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the working one - [Result Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevron/ChVU9/)**

**HTML**

```
<td><i class="line"></i>This Is demo Text</td>
```

**CSS**

```
.line{
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    top:50%;
    left:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an image (1px width and height of your td) and use background-image property in css like this:

```
td{
    background-image: url('relative/path/to/your/image');
}
```

Comment: I'd say `background: url(...) 0 center repeat-x; `

Answer (score 0):

I just tested doing it with a span, and it worked, but other solutions might be much more elegant.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GAlFr